# Поиск неверного ответа в тестах

Tags: python, алгоритм, комбинаторика

есть тест. допустим 20 вопросов. всего вопросов пусть будет 1000.
N людей проходит тест 1 раз и получает отчет в диапазоне 0-100%. Допустим 50 человек.
Задача, найти алгоритм как можно выявить неверные ответы в тесте.

Т.е. вопросы людям даются шафлом. и могут попасться все верные, а могут совершить ошибки.
пока кроме исключения вопросов из тех групп которые сдали на 100% не придумала как находить другие.
пример. у 1 человека результат 80% значит около 2 вопросов неверно. как их найти, если знаем какие вопросы давали людям, и какой их итоговый балл.

upd: подробнее
50 человек сдают тест. каждому попадается по 20 разных вопросов. из общего банка вопросов в 100 вопросов. т.е. с кем-то из 50 человек будут пересечения. по итогу теста 50 человек получает процент верных ответов.0-100%. какой вопрос попался людям мы знаем, и как он ответил тоже. получается матрица сроки это человеки и их варианты ответа. по столбцам 20 ответов 21 это набранный балл. как по этим данным найти те вопросы где были совершены ошибки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: вы бы перечитали, что спросили и перефразировали - звучит очень непонятно, раз 5ый уже перечитываю

Comment: ваша задача такая: всего есть 1000 вопросов, для каждого из 50 пользователей случайно выбирается 20 из них. Известно на сколько каждый пользователь ответил правильно. Определить на какие конкретно вопросы каждый пользователь ответил неправильно используя данную выше информацию Так?

Comment: @Zhihar из того что стало понятно мне - не так. Вроде как надо найти вопросы с не верными ответами.  То есть вопросы, в которых нет верного ответа, либо все отвечают "не верно".

Comment: а как ее вообще можно решить - по 20 вопросов из 1000, 50 человек. Допустим каждый получил непересекающиеся с другими вопросы (нет общих вопросов). Тогда вообще определить вопрос плохой или ответ неправильный. Или по условию пользователь всегда отвечает правильно?

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно

Comment: 50 человек сдают тест. каждому попадается по 20 разных вопросов. из общего банка вопросов в 100 вопросов. т.е. с кем-то из 50 человек будут пересечения. по итогу теста 50 человек получает процент верных ответов.0-100%. какой вопрос попался людям мы знаем, и как он ответил тоже. получается матрица сроки это человеки и их варианты ответа. по столбцам 20 ответов 21 это набранный балл. как по этим данным найти те вопросы где были совершены ошибки.

Comment: Циклами и находите, в базе храните вопросы со спец айди, отправляйте с базы вопрос пользователю, после того как он ответит, храните как вам удобно данные можно в словаре, чтобы был айди вопрос на который ответил пользователь и сам вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Задача целочисленного линейного программирования. Набор уравнений похож на систему линейных уравнений, только переменные `Aij` ограничены значениями 0 и 1.

```
A00  +       A02 = Sum0
A10  + A11       = Sum1
0 <= Aij <= 1
```

Если решение (каким-нибудь ILP Solver-ом) существует и единственно - получаете `Aij=1` для верного ответа юзера `i` на вопрос `j`, 0 для неверного.

При приведённых в вопросе числах существование единственного решения сомнительно.

Comment: j это вся база вопросов? i вопрос. а А что такое? и как коэффициент поставить? ведь заранее неизвестно какие ответы верные. получается A-участник, j вопрос в базе i вопрос пользователя. i это переменная.0/1

Comment: j - это номер вопроса в базе вопросов, i - человек, A  - answer, Aij - ответ i-го человека на j-й вопрос